# Can I create index after loading documents in sharded mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, sharding

We are doing migration from a collection(old collection) to another mongodb collection(new collection) in Azure cosmos. So while this migration we haven't created index in new collection and migrated all documents to new collection. So can we create index now in new collection or it should have created earlier before migration(before loading documents).Both(old & new collection) are sharded collection. Size of new collection is 211 gb, if I create index it will account for certain memory consumption(index size). So I would like to know is there any impact if we create index after loading documents? Are we good to create index after loading documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create indexes after the migration as well without any issues.

Please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing) documentation for the commands to create various index types.
The commands to track progress of the indexing operation are also provided on the same document.

Comment: Hi @Kalyan Chanumolu-MSFT, can i drop default indexes('$**_1') for the collection(mongodb ver 3.6) which hold approx 211gb data already and some streaming process continuously writing to these collection(not migration).From provided link, i could understand 'index updates' is background job so i believe, it(deleting default index) wont affect write process, right now even we dont fire read query to this collection, only stream writing. So i think we are good to drop default index, pls point out if see any discrepancy